# Is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle based on experimental imprecision in measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

As far as I understand, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle states that the more one of the conjugate quantities are known, the less the other is known. So for instance, if the velocity of a particle is known more precisely, its location will become known less precisely. 
I also read somewhere that it's because if you direct some ray at the moving particle, the ray will reflect, giving the former position of the particle, but the whole collision between the ray and the particle changes the particle's momentum, thus only one can be measured at a time which is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. 
In that case, if there is an indefinitely precise measuring device that can detect the particle's position and velocity at the same time, can the Heisenberg uncertainty principle disproved?
Also, does the Heisenberg uncertainty principle apply only to subatomic particles, or large objects too?

Comment: The uncertainty referred to in the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is _intrinsic_; it represents the limit of what a perfect measuring device would be able to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isn't the uncertainty principle just non-fundamental limitations in our current technology that could be removed in a more advanced civilization?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24068/)

Comment: The HUP is a purely mathematical  consequence of the basic assumptions of quantum mechanics.  Your arguments would apply equally well (or poorly) to classical mechanics, but classical mechanics has no HUP, so your arguments cannot be right.  See my answer here for more:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/386894/4993